# Rails 4: MySQL 2 error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have upgraded my project to Rails 4 but Mysql is having an error:

`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> nil OR delete_by < 1)) ORDER BY`t_dest_boards`.`id`ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT`t_dest_boards`.* FROM`t_dest_boards`WHERE (m_section_id = 1 AND v_employee_id = '02001' AND registration_date = '2017-02-13' AND (delete_by => nil OR delete_by < 1)) ORDER BY`t_dest_boards`.`id`ASC LIMIT 1`

in this line of code:

`tdest_tmp = TDestBoard.where("m_section_id = ? AND v_employee_id = ? AND registration_date = ? AND (delete_by => nil OR delete_by < ?)", primary_section.m_section_id, params[:id], params[:tdaily_dates]["#{id}"], 1).first`

What could be the right way of doing this in Rails 4? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `delete_by => nil OR delete_by < 1`  could you double check this condition on the query and what is `nil` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete_by => nil` might be the code that throws error. if you want to check whether a field is nil, use 'IS NULL' in condition. so change your code as follows

```
tdest_tmp = TDestBoard.where("m_section_id = ? AND v_employee_id = ? AND registration_date = ? AND (delete_by IS NULL OR delete_by < ?)", primary_section.m_section_id, params[:id], params[:tdaily_dates]["#{id}"], 1).first
```

Comment: Thanks @jith! Fixed it